# How to expand a column containing vectors in a data frame

Tags: r

How can I expand the values in "Code range" column? My data has two columns: `Code Range` and `Lable`. I want to add a third column to the data frame that will contain the individual values from the vectors. How do I do that in R?

```
Code Range  Lable Codes(new Column)
61000:61055 Test1 61001
61000:61055 Test1 61002
61000:61055 Test1 61003
61000:61055 Test1 61004
61000:61055 Test1 61005
  .
  .
61000:61055 Test1 61055
0356T:0358T Test2 0356T
0356T:0358T Test2 0357T
0356T:0358T Test2 0358T
S9090:S9090 Test3 S9090
0062T:0062T Test4 0062T
```

No, I am looking for something like

```
Code Range  df.Lable Codes(new Column to be added)
61000:61055 Test1 61001
61000:61055 Test1 61002
61000:61055 Test1 61003
61000:61055 Test1 61004
61000:61055 Test1 61005
  .
  .
61000:61055 Test1 61055
0356T:0358T Test2 0356T
0356T:0358T Test2 0357T
0356T:0358T Test2 0358T
S9090:S9090 Test3 S9090
0062T:0062T Test4 0062T
```

Comment: What would those expaded code ranges look like?

Comment: `str_split_fixed(Code_Range, ":", 2)`?

Comment: This might be hard to answer.  Can you give a general format for the label?

Comment: Label is a string field

Answer (score 0):

For a base R option, we can make two calls to `sub` to extract the starting and ending strings of your code ranges.

```
df$start <- sub(":.*$",    "", df$Code_Range)
df$end   <- sub("^[^:]+:", "", df$Code_Range)

df
   Code_Range Label start   end
1 61000:61055 Test1 61000 61055
2 0356T:0356T Test2 0356T 0356T
3 S9090:S9090 Test3 S9090 S9090
4 0062T:0062T Test4 0062T 0062T
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
df <- read.table(text="Code_Range  Lable
61000:61055 Test1
0356T:0356T Test2
S9090:S9090 Test3
0062T:0062T Test4", header=T)

library(stringr)
data.frame(str_split_fixed(df$Code_Range, ":", 2), df$Lable)


#      X1    X2 df.Lable
# 1 61000 61055    Test1
# 2 0356T 0356T    Test2
# 3 S9090 S9090    Test3
# 4 0062T 0062T    Test4
```

Comment: @TinaEgbuonu Your original question was incomplete because of lack of data.  This answer is reasonable based on your original question.